# Shell - Using an environment variable with ccrypt

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am having problems using a program called ['ccrypt'](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/) which is used to encrypt files. The way in which I am using it is as follows:

```
ccrypt -e -E $cryptograph `find . -type f | sed -n -e '$i{p;q}'`
```

where `-e` means that the program is running in encrypt mode. My problem is as follows:

The manual for the command says that `-E` is used to read the passphrase for the encryption from an environment variable using this syntax:

```
-E var
```

and as such I have set it to be the passphrase I want as below:

```
cryptograph="Example_passphrase"
```

However, when I run the code as shown above, an error message appears as follows:

> ccrypt: environment variable Example_passphrase does not exist.

Does anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers, exporting the variable and removing the "$" worked but now I face a new problem:

```
"sed -n -e '$i{p;q}'"
```

The shell says:

> ccrypt: {p;q}: No such file or directory

However, if I exchange $i for a number then the program works to an extent. What is the correct syntax for using the variable 'i' here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to export the environment variable (until it is exported, it is just a variable, not an environment variable).

```
export cryptograph="Example_passphrase"
ccrypt -e -E cryptograph `find . -type f | sed -n -e '$i{p;q}'`
```

Specifying just the name is crucial (no `$`).  Otherwise, the value of the variable — the passphrase itself — is in the command line arguments and visible to `ps` etc.  We can debate whether the environment is secure (think of the `/proc` file system), but it is several steps better than including the passphrase itself on the command line.

---

From the comments, it appears that you might be best off doing something like:

```
find . -type f -exec ccrypt -e -E cryptograph {} ';'
```

One major advantage of this is that it sidesteps all the problems with blanks and other odd-ball characters in file names.  If the `ccrypt` command accepts multiple files, you can probably replace the quoted `';'` with `+` (which doesn't need quotes) and a single command will encrypt all the files.

Comment: Thanks, this has worked, but now there is a problem with the later part of the command ie "sed -n -e '$i{p;q}'" The script says: no such file or directory. However, if I exchange $i for a number then the program works to an extent. What is the correct syntax for using the variable 'i' here?

Comment: You need to use double quotes around the `sed` script: `sed -n -e "/$i/{p;q}"` (noting that I've added slashes to make it search for the file named by `$i`, though that name had better not itself contain any slash).  The shell does not expand variables (or anything else) inside single quotes.  It looks like you could simplify your life by using `grep` instead of `sed`: `find ... | grep "$i"` would achieve the same result.  Indeed, `find . -type f -name "$i"` without any `sed` or `grep` would probably do what you're after.

Comment: With the single quotes, `sed` reads to the end of the file without printing anything; then, on the last line, it attempts to do an `i` command, which inserts text.  Normally, you add a backslash, and then the text to be inserted on subsequent lines also ending with a backslash up to the last line to be inserted which does not end with a backslash.  On Mac OS X, `man sed | sed -n -e '$i{p;q}'` produces a single line of output `{p;q}`, which is then (in your scenario) passed to the ccrypt command, which cannot find the file.

Comment: There is no file named by "$i" instead, the   sed -n -e '$i{p;q}' is intended to read from the i numbered output of the find command. This means that it will, as it is in a while loop, go through all of the files in a directory and encrypt them until i is greater than the number of files when it will stop. As I said, substituting a number in directly works but the defined file gets encrypted 5 times (there are five files in the directory).

Comment: I can't fathom how/why you're doing what you say you're doing.  If you want to ask questions about the bigger context of your script, then you need to provide the bigger context so that we can see what you are attempting.  Normally, you'd simply run `find` to list the files to be encrypted, and then step through the list.  Or you'd get `find` to execute the encryption command (which also deals with problems related to blanks etc in file names).

Comment: Thanks a lot, using: `find . -type f -exec ccrypt -e -E cryptograph {} ';'` worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the name of the variable as the argument, not its value:

```
ccrypt -e -E cryptograph `...`
```

Comment: The same problem still occurs - an error message is shown but it says 'Environment variable cryptograph does not exist'.